# Is it grammatically incorrect to use "It was double the pleasure..."?

Tags: meaning-in-context, phrase-meaning

English is my second language and somebody told me that the second sentence I created is grammatically incorrect:

> It was a great pleasure to meet you. And *it was double the pleasure* to share a wonderful dinner.

Is it grammatically incorrect to use "it was double the pleasure..."?

Comment: "It was a great pleasure to meet you, and doubly so to share a wonderful diner." sounds better to me, but the only real mistake in your sentence is "you. And" should be "you, and"

Comment: "dinner", "diner" is a kind of restauraunt where people have dinner.

Comment: No, it's not grammatically incorrect. But it does sound like [a commercial for Wrigley's gum](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=F7hwvWIK1eM).

Comment: The person telling you it is 'grammatically incorrect' doesn't understand the difference between 'ungrammatical' and 'high-flown'.

Comment: Only if you're chewing Wrigley's Double Mint Gum.

Comment: No it is not grammatically incorrect.

Comment: It is acceptable, but unless “someone” gave their reason for thinking it incorrect we cannot give an answer relevant to their view. Consequently your question seems to be a request for proofreading, which we do not do.